# (PHP, MYSQL) Update multiple rows with multiple WHERE

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to PHP, now I face some strange issue about updating the value.

From these codes

```
            for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++){

                $sql = ("UPDATE applicant_skill SET App_skill_performance_score = '".$s_score[$i]."', App_skill_knowledge_score = ".$k_score[$i]."'  WHERE App_Data_ID ='".$a_id."'  && Position_ID = '".$p_id."'  && Skill_ID = '".$skill_id[$i]."' ");


                $resultt = "";

                if ($conn->query($sql) == TRUE) {
                   $resultt = "FINISH";
                } else {
                   $resultt = "ERROR";
                }

        }
```

At first I use INSERT and it works fine. Now I change to UPDATE but it updates nothing (the field is already in database waiting for update).

I don't know where mistake is, please help.

Comment: Mysql is not php... not && but AND

Comment: @nospor thank you !!! it works now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$sscrore = $s_score[$i];
$kscore = $k_score[$i];
$aid = $a_id;
$pid = $p_id;
$skillid = $skill_id[$i];

 $sql = ("UPDATE applicant_skill SET App_skill_performance_score = '$sscrore', App_skill_knowledge_score = '$kscore'  WHERE App_Data_ID ='$aid'  AND Position_ID = '$pid'  AND Skill_ID = '$skillid' ");
```

Basically, you are missing one ' before ".$k_score[$i]."'

use AND instead of &&

Comment: @sagi ohh yes...I missed last comment by 13 seconds...haa...haa...haaa